# SftpRemoteFileTemplate does not work with RemoteDirectoryExpression when @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Below is the configuration I am using

```
@Autowired
private SftpRemoteFileTemplate outboundTemplate;

@Autowired
private SftpConfig config;


@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpOutputGenericChannel")
public MessageHandler simplehandler() {
    SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(outboundTemplate, FileExistsMode.APPEND);
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(config.getDirectory()));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator((Message<?> message) -> ((String) message.getHeaders().get(KEY)));
    handler.setUseTemporaryFileName(false);
    return handler;
}
```

I have created Sessionfactory, CachingSessionfactory and SftpRemoteFileTemplte in a seperate Config class and they are getting instantiated properly, below are the logs for the same.

```
2020-11-27 01:15:17.742 [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'cachingSessionFactory'
2020-11-27 01:15:17.744 [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'sftpSessionFactory'
2020-11-27 01:15:17.778 [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'cachingSessionFactory' via factory method to bean named 'sftpSessionFactory'
2020-11-27 01:15:17.783 [main] o.s.integration.util.SimplePool          : Target pool size changed by -2147483637, now 10
2020-11-27 01:15:54.434 [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'outboundTemplate'
2020-11-27 01:15:54.435 [main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from bean name 'outboundTemplate' via factory method to bean named 'cachingSessionFactory'
```

When I execute this code Spring DEBUG logs shows that the file is been sent to the server successfully, but actually file is not getting uploaded to the server.

but if I change implementation of `MessageHandler` to,

```
SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(cachingSessionFactory), FileExistsMode.APPEND);
```

it starts working and file actually gets uploaded to the server, not sure why this is happening ?

One more observation when I use `@Autowired SftpRemoteFileTemplate` with `handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("headers['remote_directory']")` it works perfectly fine.

I want to understand how SftpRemoteTemplate is working here and what is the best practice suggested ?

*Note : SpringBoot v2.4.0 Spring integration : 5.4.1, faced the similer issue with boot v2.2.6.RELEASE*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use the same `SftpRemoteFileTemplate` in other places and you also modify it over there for other options. In fact something like `handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression()` does a delegation, and therefore mutation, to the provided `SftpRemoteFileTemplate`:

```
/**
 * Specify a remote directory path SpEL expression.
 * @param remoteDirectoryExpression the remote directory expression
 * @see RemoteFileTemplate#setRemoteDirectoryExpression(Expression)
 */
public void setRemoteDirectoryExpression(Expression remoteDirectoryExpression) {
    this.remoteFileTemplate.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(remoteDirectoryExpression);
}
```

So, when another place does a similar modification, you end up with a race condition and your file may be transferred to a different place.

The best practice is to treat a `RemoteFileTemplate` as a `prototype` and have an instance per channel adapter. Or just use another ctor - only a `SessionFactory`-based:

```
/**
 * @param sessionFactory the session factory.
 * @see FileTransferringMessageHandler#FileTransferringMessageHandler
 * (SessionFactory)
 */
public SftpMessageHandler(SessionFactory<LsEntry> sessionFactory)
```

We probably need to revise the logic in the `FileTransferringMessageHandler` to reject a mutation for externally provided `RemoteFileTemplate`. Feel free to raise a GH issue and we will see what we can do in the next major version, where we can do some breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I will then now stick with new  SftpRemoteFileTemplate only. I have tried using PROTOTYPE scope and multiple other options as well like setting remote directory while initializing SftpRemoteFileTemplate and not calling handler's method etc but results are same..  I can use another ctor which only uses SessionFactory but not sure it will give me a option to write the file in Append mode ? So that I dont need to use SftpRemoteFileTemplate everywhere